# Multiline Notification title

Tags: android, push-notification

I need to show the notification  title in two lines but am not able to do so. I have tried to use setStyle() for this but doesn't seem to be working.

My Notification builder code ::

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_not);
mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
mBuilder.setContentTitle("")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().setBigContentTitle(notTitle))
        .setContentText(notBodyInt)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Still the notification title is getting wrapped up in a single line.

Comment: Not sure but I guess you can hack a way around using https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded#message-style

Comment: @Rohit5k2, i have built custom notification using RemoteViews and have acheived what exactly i was looking for, but still this remains a mystery for me why i wasn't able to do that this way, as this solution is the simple and more precise solution to this.
Moreover, i'll try to find out the reason and will share it here.

Comment: You should post your solution here as answer. Would help many.

Comment: Yes, i'll post it soon